# Solving for V+ using Vout

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, feedback, kirchhoffs-laws

I have been instructed to use KVL/KCL on the following circuit to try and figure out an equation for V+:

[image]

I've also been given a hint, saying that I can use the Vout from the previous time step of my simulation to solve for their values in the current step:

$$V^+ = F(V_{out}(n-1))$$

$$V_{out}(n) = A_v(V^+-V^-)$$

Can I be pushed in the right direction? I know I can represent V– as Vc(n-1), but I'm not sure how to go about V+.

edit: There are 2 answers I have come up with...

1) $$\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2} V_{out}(n-1)$$

2) $$\frac{V_{out}(n-1)}{A_v}$$

edit 2: some values that may be of importance -

Vin = 0; % Voltage to the noninverting terminal

Vref = 0; % Voltage of the common port

Vcc = 5; % Positive Voltage Rail

Vee = -5; % Negative Voltage Rail

Av = 1e6; % Operational Amplifier Open-Loop Gain

R_1 = 100000; % Input Resistance, Ohms

R_2 = 100000; % Positive Feedback Resistance, Ohms

R = 7583.3; % Negative Feedback Resistance, Ohms (tuned for 60Hz)

C = 1E-6; % Capacitor Capacitance, Farads

Comment: Vin+=Vin- when Vout is in the linear range.  Assume Av is infinite.

Comment: Not sure if it makes things more clear, but I provided a second edit to the OP

Comment: Use my hint above with KVL  using Vin,Vout

Comment: Doesn't that summing point constraint not apply with positive feedback?

Comment: KVL rules apply for both feedback +,-  for steady state, dynamic time is of interest on output.  Yes positive feedback implies hysteresis,

Comment: Are you implying V+ = Vc(n-1) ?

Comment: No actually it is an Astable Oscillator with saturating output square wave on + and triangle wave on - input. So KVL will tell you the Vin+ levels. and Vin- RC time tells you the slew rate to reach those levels

Comment: I'm getting a little confused now! How can that help me with the original question: finding an equation for V+?

Comment: If you know the response for a simple RC circuit and a simple R-R divider then you consider the use with positive feedback like a comparator. So this means Vin+ is not a steady state voltage, only for a fixed time determined when the voltages match at the inputs and the output toggles

Comment: Oh yes I know that. I'm not looking for a single numerical answer. I have to come up with an equation for V+. that is where I am struggling

Comment: Vin+=R1/(R1+R2)  * {Vcc:Vee} 2 states  ( if rail to rail type outputs

Comment: Is that the same as my R1/(R1+R2) * Vout(n-1) answer?

Comment: it says I can use the Vout from the previous time step of my simulation to solve for their values in the current step

Comment: Yes  . So the Vin- triangle swing is 50% of Vout for R1/(R1+R2)=1/2  so the Ratio and supply voltage changes output frequency.. Similar to a RC schmitt trigger logic Astable except those have 1/3 positive feedback

Comment: It looks like V- slowly goes from -2.5 V to 2.5 V (back and forth) whereas V+ is constantly at -2.5 V and jumps to 2.5 V (back and forth). is this normal?

Comment: With 50% positive feedback, yes that is normal from +/-5Vcc. We call that an Astable Oscillator and is often done with a 74HC14

Comment: Great. Final thing: Would anything change if the gain was changed to 1e5 or 1e9?

Comment: Av has no effect compared to feedback ratio of 1/2 or even 1/10

Comment: Agreed. But if I made the gain really low, to like say just 1, there would be a noticeable difference right?

Comment: Correct, feedback error is inverse to gain.  in order to oscillate , Barkhausen criteria demands overall gain >1 for positive feedback. so minimum gain must be >2 for feedback ratio of 1/2